# Get all points from a ShapeFile (.shp) in Java

Tags: java, postgis, arcgis, shapefile

I'd like to use [shapefile](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) (.shp) data in Java.

A sample file I have looks like this:

0105000000010000000102000000070000003085EF7995215FC0E0A2FEADF6E648400439100E8D215FC0B04AF9E80BE7484048CC79E78C215FC0F885E4F20CE74840B86EEC078C215FC0E80213FC12E74840A4B69A9694215FC07011B67744E7484008E900F396215FC04867DE1949E7484004D90A7EA1215FC0A8F7E1AE4BE74840

How can I can extract/decode all points (lat/lon) in this shapefile in java?

Comment: you have to write a parser for the file format using the very specification that you linked. You can use the basic File IO operations found in the standard java api such as `RandomAccessFile` to more easily access the components you need, or you can buffer the whole file into memory and parse it from RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty bad question my friend.  Try to provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

If that binary you posted is really an .shp (file with the associated "helper" files such as .shx, .prj, etc), you can use a library such as [GeoTools](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html) to read the file.

Attempting to read the file "by hand" with `RandomAccessFile` is unnecessary unless you really want to reinvent the wheel.